# How to Get distance between coordinate AR Location Based

Tags: android, geolocation, location, augmented-reality

How to Get distance between coordinate on  AR Location Based

I lerning from com.cobyplain.augmentreality.AugmentRealityStep4
(  https://github.com/cplain/augmented-reality-tutorial )

How to show distance with mSport and mPaint on screen

http://upic.me/i/a1/dckar.png

Answer (score 0):

First of all always share your code. We`re not here to give you codes but instead you help you achieve it.

If you want to show the distance between your position and some POI position that you need two things: `Your position` and the `POI position` which have both your coordinates and the POI coordinates. This can be done via manual calculation or can be done using an API.

I recommend [**Google Maps API**](https://developers.google.com/maps/) for this since their function include those of which you have asked.